# How to make a child process waits for its sibling?

Tags: c, unix, ipc, process

I am solving it by use of IPC as suggested by [Mat][1] but still I am not able to do
 it   and by the way it is sample exercise,not a homework! but i have exam coming so
 please help   me here...:)
 Somebody pinpoint me here what am i doing wrong.Kid2 does not send or parent does not  recieve any signal from kid 2.

Thanx.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<sys/wait.h>  
#include<wait.h>  
#include<signal.h>  

void my_handler_for_kid2(int sig_num){  
  printf("KID2:Recieved SIGUSR1 from KID1\n");  
}  
void my_handler_for_parent(int sig_num){  
  printf("PARENT:Recieved SIGUSR2 from KID2\n");  
}  

int main(){  
  int status;  
 pid_t kid1,kid2;  

  void my_handler_for_kid2(int sig_num);  
  void my_handler_for_parent(int sig_num);  
  signal(SIGUSR1,my_handler_for_kid2);
  signal(SIGUSR2,my_handler_for_parent);
  kid1=fork();  
  if(kid1 < 0){  
    printf("Fork not successfull\n");  
  }  
  else if(kid1 == 0){  
    printf("I am KID1[%ld] and I am going to sleep\n",(long) getpid());  
    sleep(5);  
    printf("Just woke up!\n");  
    kill(kid2,SIGUSR1);  
      }  
  else{  
    kid2=fork();  
    if(kid2 < 0){ 
      printf("Fork not successfull\n");  
    }  
    else if(kid2 == 0){  
      printf("I am KID2[%ld] and I am going to wait for KID1 to wakeup\n",(long)       getpid());  
      pause(); 
      //signal(SIGUSR1,my_handler_for_kid2);  
      kill(getppid(),SIGUSR2);  
    }  
    else{  
      printf("Father[%ld] here and going to wait for both kids to respond to me\n",    (long) getpid());  
      pause();
      //signal(SIGUSR2,my_handler_for_parent);  
      waitpid(kid1,&status,NULL);  
      waitpid(kid2,&status,NULL);  
    }  
 }  
} 

rizwan@riz-pc:~/Documents$ ./a.out
I am KID1[2278] and I am going to sleep
 Father[2277] here and going to wait for both kids to respond to me
 I am KID2[2279] and I am going to wait for KID1 to wakeup
 Just woke up!
KID2:Recieved SIGUSR1 from KID1
^C
rizwan@riz-pc:~/Documents$ 








  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/users/635608/mat
```

Answer (score 6):

From [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html):

> The wait() and waitpid() functions shall obtain status information pertaining to **one of the caller's child processes**.

You can't use these functions to synchronize between siblings, only from one parent waiting on its children.
You'll need to use some "real" synchronization primitives to achieve what you're after (semaphores, or some other form of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)).

Comment: Write a program that fork two child, the first child sleeps for 10 sec (use system call sleep), the
second child wait for the end of the first child and prints a message related to the ended of the first
child. The father waits for the ended of the two sons and prints the id of the terminated process.

Comment: I'm not going to do your assignment for you. I explained above why your approach (using wait from on sibling to another) cannot work. Look at the IPC link I posted for options on how to communicate between the two siblings.

Comment: I am sorry but i am not asking u to do it...thanx anyways...:)

Comment: "*... need to use some "real" synchronization primitives ...*": The case described by riz could very well be solved by just using `signal()`ling related functions.

Comment: @alk: check the edit history of this post. The original code had nothing to do with what is currently visible.

Comment: @mat: Ahok I see, your "*real*" was ment to included `signal()`s ... - sry

Comment: Could you guys be more specific...tell me what am i doing wrong and where?thanx

Comment: @riz: what you did is really not what I had in mind when I asked you to edit your question. You changed your completely, rendering existing answers obsolete. That's frowned upon. I thought you needed clarifications on existing answers. Are you 100% sure that the code you have matches the output you showed, because it looks fishy to me. (Especially: kid1's pid2 variable is uninitialized as far as I can tell.)

Comment: @Mat I have rechecked it,result is same.The output belongs to the above code.which part are you referring to ?(kid1's pid2 variable)?I am sorry for the confusion i have made by editing it many times.thanx

Comment: @riz: your whole code is unreliable. Print the pid in the signal handlers (not "KIDx", the result of getpid in the handlers) and you'll see something is wrong. Also compile with full warnings enabled and fix all the problems. As for the pid2, step through your code (by reading it) along the path that leads to kid2. You'll see that variable is never initialized on that path.

Answer (score 1):

Mutex synchronization could work.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should use conditional variables. Take any tutorial from net.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Are you perhaps suggesting "condition variables"?  In any case, "search for a tutorial on the web" is not very helpful.  The best answers here provide detailed information and one or two well-selected links.